# The same stored procedure in schema doesn't work package

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure inside the package:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION (
      P_TABLE_NAME   IN VARCHAR2,
      P_STICHTAG     IN NUMBER,
      P_SUB_ID       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '*')
   IS
      SQL_TRUNCATE                   VARCHAR2 (4000);
      VVPRUEF                        VARCHAR2 (4000);
      SQL_ADD_SUBPARTITION           VARCHAR2 (4000);
      PROOF_IF_DATA                  VARCHAR2 (4000);
      PARTITION_DOES_EXIST           EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (PARTITION_DOES_EXIST, -14622);
 
      PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST_SUB   EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST_SUB, -14702);
      PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST2      EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST2, -02149);
   BEGIN
      -- Wenn keine bestimmte Subpartition angegeben ist, dann truncate auf Partition Ebene
      IF P_SUB_ID = '' OR P_SUB_ID = '*'
      THEN
         SQL_TRUNCATE :=
               'ALTER TABLE '
            || P_TABLE_NAME
            || ' TRUNCATE PARTITION FOR ('
            || P_STICHTAG
            || ') UPDATE INDEXES';
      ELSE
         SQL_TRUNCATE :=
               'ALTER TABLE '
            || P_TABLE_NAME
            || ' TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION FOR ('
            || P_STICHTAG
            || ','
            || ''''
            || P_SUB_ID
            || ''''
            || ') UPDATE INDEXES';
      END IF;
 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SQL_TRUNCATE);
   EXCEPTION
      -- Wenn diese bestimmte Subpartition bereits vorhanden ist, dann leere sie
      WHEN PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST2
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
         NULL;
      WHEN PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST_SUB
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
         NULL;
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
            -20002,
            'P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION(): ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 500));
   END P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION;
```

Inside a schema it works:

```sql
CALL BAISMART.P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION('TABLE_NAME', 20220126, 'PURTITION_NAME')
```

but when I call it from the package:

```sql
CALL BAISMART.PCK_BAIS_UTIL.P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION('TABLE_NAME', 20220126, 'PURTITION_NAME')
```

I get an error:

> SQL Error [6553] [65000]: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION'.

Code of the package itself:

```sql
-- DROP PACKAGE BAISMART.PCK_BAIS_UTIL;
 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BAISMART.PCK_BAIS_UTIL
AS
   PROCEDURE P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION;
END PCK_BAIS_UTIL;
 
 
 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BAISMART.PCK_BAIS_UTIL
AS
     ------------------------
  PROCEDURE P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION (
      P_TABLE_NAME   IN VARCHAR2,
      P_STICHTAG     IN NUMBER,
      P_SUB_ID       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '*')
   IS
      SQL_TRUNCATE                   VARCHAR2 (4000);
      VVPRUEF                        VARCHAR2 (4000);
      SQL_ADD_SUBPARTITION           VARCHAR2 (4000);
      PROOF_IF_DATA                  VARCHAR2 (4000);
      PARTITION_DOES_EXIST           EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (PARTITION_DOES_EXIST, -14622);
 
      PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST_SUB   EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST_SUB, -14702);
      PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST2      EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST2, -02149);
   BEGIN
      -- Wenn keine bestimmte Subpartition angegeben ist, dann truncate auf Partition Ebene
      IF P_SUB_ID = '' OR P_SUB_ID = '*'
      THEN
         SQL_TRUNCATE :=
               'ALTER TABLE '
            || P_TABLE_NAME
            || ' TRUNCATE PARTITION FOR ('
            || P_STICHTAG
            || ') UPDATE INDEXES';
      ELSE
         SQL_TRUNCATE :=
               'ALTER TABLE '
            || P_TABLE_NAME
            || ' TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION FOR ('
            || P_STICHTAG
           || ','
            || ''''
            || P_SUB_ID
            || ''''
            || ') UPDATE INDEXES';
      END IF;
 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SQL_TRUNCATE);
   EXCEPTION
      -- Wenn diese bestimmte Subpartition bereits vorhanden ist, dann leere sie
      WHEN PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST2
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
         NULL;
      WHEN PARTITION_DOES_NOT_EXIST_SUB
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (SQLERRM);
         NULL;
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
            -20002,
            'P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION(): ' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 500));
   END P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION;
 
 
END PCK_BAIS_UTIL;
```

Has anybody any idea why it can happen?

Comment: Doesn't make sense at first glance. **However**, statements you posted as "examples" are *dummy*. Would you mind posting what you really executed?

Comment: @Littlefoot stored procedure is as it is. Actually I call the following SQL: CALL BAISMART.PCK_BAIS_UTIL.P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION('EAEGIF',20210630,'CBAT      ');

Comment: (Yes, I know - procedure itself is *as is*). Procedure expects 3 parameters: a string, a number, a string. That's what you provided (though, should the last really have additional space?). Is there, by any chance, mismatch in package **specification** and its **body**? Perhaps an overloaded procedure?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the standalone procedure and package specification declarations too - not necessarily the whole procedure code, just enough to recreate. (With dummy code, [it works as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=811fbea20682f95d8f0713a6c379688f) - so we need to figure out what you are doing differently.)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, you are right, I occasionally removed ')' when I was pasting my code to Stackoverflow. I have fixed the code. I have double checked schema, database and connection, must be the same. I have also tried to recompile the procedure using: ALTER PACKAGE BAISMART. PCK_BAIS_UTIL

Comment: @AlexPoole  I have updated the code to add also source code of the package. And also thanks for help!

Comment: OK, but if that is your real code, then your package body will still be invalid - do you get a compilation error/warning that you've ignored?

Comment: What did I tell you? **mismatch in package specification and its body?** Better read what people say (if you ask for help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package specification and body don't match; so you will get a compilation error from the body, and your call [will get PLS-00306](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=18570d520a167ac2e512d1ea309f1f4d).

Your specification says:

```
   PROCEDURE P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION;
```

so the procedure takes no arguments. That should match the body:

```
   PROCEDURE P_TRUNC_I_SUB_PARTITION (
      P_TABLE_NAME   IN VARCHAR2,
      P_STICHTAG     IN NUMBER,
      P_SUB_ID       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '*'
   );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=811fbea20682f95d8f0713a6c379688f) with the modified specification.

Comment: thanks for the solution! Now I see the problem. Funny, but I didn't get any compilation error. Maybe some settings from our DWH team have an influence on it.